# Eclipse RCP: How do use bigger bmp-file for product export and EclipseNSIS

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to export my application as eclipse product which works. In the end I want to create a classical installer, probably using EclipseNSIS (never used before).

In my config.ini.product-file I have listed all BMP-files which eclipse should use as launcher icon. The problem is that eclipse only uses the 16x16 8-bit icon. When I create a desktop shortcut the icon looks like a mess because I had to scale it down.

Is it somehow possible to tell eclipse to use the bigger versions of the BMP-files, like the 32x32 32-bit one?

I haven't tried EclipseNSIS yet because I still try to solve this while only exporting as eclipse product. Is it maybe possible in EclipseNSIS to use one of the bigger versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make myself an .ico-file using GIMP. Using this .ico-file, the image looks fine. Using seperate icons it seems that it is only possible to use the 16x16 8-bit version.